# How to mock RequestContext.getCurrentContext()?

Tags: netflix-zuul, zuul-testing

I am new bee here stuck in one problem regarding Zuul. I am writing test cases for Zuul filters first I want to know do I need to write UT's for my Zuul filters if yes then I am writing unit test of `shouldFilter()` method of my zuul filter in which I have to mock `requestContext`.

How can I achieve this goal ?

I have already mocked `HttpServletRequest` and `RequestContext` but when I go in debug mode it shows as **null** .. what am I missing ?

```
@Override
public boolean shouldFilter() {

    RequestContext requestContext = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
    HttpServletRequest request = requestContext.getRequest();
    if (request.getHeader(Constants.AUTHORIZATION.getValue()) != null) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

That is my original method

```
@Test
public void testShouldFilter(){

    MockHttpServletRequest request = new MockHttpServletRequest(context);
    request.addHeader("Authorization","123");
    RequestContext rc = new RequestContext();
    rc.setRequest(request);

    Mockito.when(requestContext.getCurrentContext().getRequest()).thenReturn(request);
    doReturn(request).when(requestContext).getRequest();
    doReturn(rc).when(requestContext)
    Mockito.when(request.getHeader()).thenReturn(rc);
    Mockito.when(RequestContextHolder.(Constants.AUTHORIZATION.getValue())).thenReturn(request.getHeader("Authorization"));
   boolean Sf = authorizationFilter.shouldFilter();
    Assert.assertFalse(Sf);
}
```

That is my Unit test

and Sorry for bad English

I expect request should have any mock object so that it can compare header value but its returning null.

Answer (score 2):

```
RequestContext.testSetCurrentContext(new RequestContext());
```

or

```
MockHttpServletRequest request = new MockHttpServletRequest("GET", "/url");
RequestContext context = new RequestContext();
context.setRequest(request);
RequestContext.testSetCurrentContext(context);
```

Unit tests for filters are not something super good, but why not, it is up to you

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion i have found this function later .. i.e testSetCurrentContext will try it soon hope it works .. thanks again :)

Comment: It must :)

Check this https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/blob/master/spring-cloud-netflix-zuul/src/test/java/org/springframework/cloud/netflix/zuul/filters/ProxyRequestHelperTests.java#L60

@AyubAhmed